# One fetch request creates many GET requests on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

Here is my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TutorialList from "./TutorialList";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Home = () => {
  const [tutorials, setTutorials] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Fetching data");
    fetch("http://192.168.212.52:8080/api/tutorials/all/")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
        console.log("Getting json from response");
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setTutorials(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="home">
      {console.log(tutorials)}
      {tutorials && (
        <TutorialList tutorials={tutorials} title={"All tutorials"} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
Home.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
};
export default Home;
```

I expect this to make 1 get request to the server, which returns the data
that is then rendered with react.

What it actually does is make more than 10
requests to the server, still rendering the data after **all** the requests
finish.  I can see the requests both from the server logs and from the browser
networking dev tools.

However, the `Fetching data` and `Getting json from response` logs only execute
once, as expected.

Comment: clearly your real code must be different since you claim that `"Getting json from response"` is logged AT ALL - that code would NEVER log that

Comment: What are the other requests?  Are they resources from a new page that is loaded into the browser?

Comment: Also, your code appears likely to have asynchronous design issues since you're doing a `return()` BEFORE the `fetch()` has completed and expecting the returned data to contain the results of the asynchronous operation (which will not be available yet).

Comment: @Bravo Sorry,  I reversed the `return` and the `console.log("Getting json from response")`.  In the real code it is the other way around, so `console.log()` runs first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `fetch` requests a resource from the network, it runs asynchronously. This said, if you want to get to run it inside a `useEffect` it might be that if you wrap it in an `async function` it should work. However, keep in mind that it's not the argument of this hook itself `async` but another function that you define inside. For instance,

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Fetching data");
    async function retrieveData() {
      const json = await fetch("http://192.168.212.52:8080/api/tutorials/all/")
      const data = await response.json()
      setTutorials(data)
      console.log("Got json from response");
    }
    retrieveData()
  }, []);
```

Comment: functionally identical to OP's code